# CakePHP - Set Default Field Values in the Model

Tags: cakephp

How do you set a default value for a field in a model?

EDIT:

I have tried the method using _schema as suggested, but the default value is not being used.

```
public $_schema = array(
    'newsletter' => array(
        'default' => 1
    ),
);
```

Comment: what's stopping you from doing this in the database?

Comment: I have tried the method described in the link, can't seem to get it working.

Comment: @freshest Which method? Searching on Google?

Comment: @elitalon The _schema method.

Comment: @freshest Try this: http://snook.ca/archives/cakephp/cakephp_setting

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using. Especially with cake2 and now cake3 out there.

Answer (score 1):

you should always try to set default values from the controller:
http://www.dereuromark.de/tag/default-values/

Comment: For more recent visitors: Be sure to scroll down Mark's explanation to see his CakePHP 2.x and 3.x updates.

Comment: default values should be set in the model don't you think?
probably in the beforesave method, otherwise you have multiple controller actions that set default values

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to set the default value in the database?  I don't really see why you would want to do it CakePHP side...

Comment: So that the application is portable, at present we do not know what database the app will be using.

Comment: OP's reason was legit - but thanks @jwg2s - this was a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

As the above suggestions do not work for me, so I have found my own. The answer is very similar to the written above, but with one little correction. (works with CakePHP 2.6.1)

The default value can be set in the controller in *add* function ("request" is needed).

```
$this->request->data['Country']['hasFlag'] = 1;
```

Full code example:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Country->create();
        if ($this->Country->save($this->request->data)) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
    $this->request->data['Country']['hasFlag'] = 1;  // default value passing to the view
}
```

---

**Some philosophy:**
1) **Why this is needed** - If we have a boolean attribute in the database, the newly created object in Cakephp does not take into the account default values from database. And if we leave checkbox unchecked in the Add form of the new object and submit it to the database - it means this attribute value is *false* (not *value not set*)
2) **Is this an ideal place to set default value?** - No, this is not an ideal place, as all information about the Object and its data must be in the Model, but I haven't managed to assign default value in the model. Even using *_schema* variable or *create* function.

Comment: This completes my answer from below.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value in database and get it managed in schema, e.g.:

```
public $items = array(
    'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'length' => 10, 'unsigned' => false, 'key' => 'primary'),
    'quantity' => array('type' => 'decimal', 'null' => false, 'default' => '1.00', 'length' => '12,2', 'unsigned' => false),
    //                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    'indexes' => array(
        'PRIMARY' => array('column' => 'id', 'unique' => 1),
    ),
    'tableParameters' => array('charset' => 'utf8', 'collate' => 'utf8_spanish_ci', 'engine' => 'InnoDB')
);
```

This default value can be read later in model or controller though the model's `schema` property:

```
// Controller example
$itemSchema = $this->Item->schema();
$defaultQuantity = $itemSchema['quantity']['default'];
// ... or:
$quantityInfo = $this->Item->schema('quantity');
$defaultQuantity = $quantityInfo['default'];
```

In recent PHP versions it can be a one-liner:

```
$defaultQuantity = $this->Item->schema('quantity')['default'];
```

This works in Cake/2.5 with MySQL adapter (no idea of other scenarios).

Answer (score 0):

databases get big, so you cannot remember all those defaults you've set. Let's keep it simple:

1. You set default values in the controller (it's easy to read the code, if default values for certain actions are set at the beginning as class properties).

For example:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
private $registerDefaults = array(
    'group_id' => '1'
);

public function register() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        /*
        * This is where you set default value
        * Here's what I do for default group that user should be assigned to
        */
        $this->request->data['User']['group_id'] = $this->registerDefaults['group_id'];

        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You have been successfully registered.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('We're unable register this user.'));
    }
}
}
```

You can't always remember default values set in the database if you've got about 60-80 tables with complicated relations.

AND

My advice is that you don't set defaults that depend on your current settings, be more flexible: create configuration table or set defaults in AppController in order to find it wth a blink of an eye.

Comment: And, what's more, what if defaults change? What if default value is not valid now?